# How many simple graphs (up to isomorphism) have 6 vertices and 8 edges and admit a Hamiltonian circuit

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

How many simple graphs (up to isomorphism) have 6 vertices and 8 edges and admit a Hamiltonian circuit?

Apparently the answer is 6, but how would you prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Such a graph is $C_6$ with two extra edges.  Enumerate the number of ways up to isomorphism to add two edges to $C_6$.

Comment: how do you know for sure that it is $C6$ with two extra edges?

Comment: @CarlisleManson A Hamilton circuit is a cycle of length 6, and it has a total of eight edges so there must be two extra.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are the 6 graphs you need.

[image]